# How does one launch PhpPgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql

I just installed postgresql, php5 and in particular PhpPgAdmin using Ubuntu's synaptic app.  The PHP is running fine, the http server (lighttpd) is working fine, and I can do pg a the command line.  The only thing that remains a mystery is PhpPgAdmin - just how does one fire it up to use it?     I am clueless about the proper means of starting PhpPgAdmin; it isn't explained anywhere on the site for it.   I tried typing phppgadmin at a bash command prompt, and entering "http://phppgsdmin/" and "http://localhost/phppgadmin" as wild guesses in the address bar  in a browser - nothing happens.  What is the secret?

BTW, i'm only serving http on localhost, doing purely private web development.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up phppgadmin in the lighty config?

```
alias.url = ("/pgadmin" => "/usr/share/phpPgAdmin")
```

You also have to enable mod_alias in Lighty (and restart it) and then "http://localhost/pgadmin" should work ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you make Apache aware of PhpPgAdmin? You need to include the following line in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
Include /etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf
```

You may also need to restart Apache for it to spring up:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

You should then be able to access PhpPgAdmin from the following address:

> http://localhost/PhpPgAdmin

Comment: I'm not using apache.  Does it have to run even if i'm already using lightppd?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I missed you weren't using Apache. I'll post another answer if I figure it out for lighttpd.

Comment: If there's a way to run two http servers at the same time, maybe that'll be easiest just to get the darn thing up for use.

Comment: Of course there is, you can install Apache listening on another port.